# How to get cookie details of the request in ruby using rest client

Tags: ruby, cookies, rest-client

If I am making this get request using rest-client gem

```
https://www.google.co.in/
```

I want get the following details:-

1. cookie
2. expire date

Also i want to remove the cookie(like we do clear cookies in browser).

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following with rest-client:

```
request = RestClient.get 'https://www.google.co.in/'
```

then inspect the cookies you have with

```
request.cookies
```

but from what I've seen there's no expire date.

To remove the cookies do the following

```
request.cookies.clear
```